# Player jumps when it touches the ground but double jumps if I dont use my jump

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

[image]

```
[...]
    // jump
    float verticleMove = joyStick.Vertical;
    if (verticleMove >= .1f && isGrounded)
    {
        body.AddForce(new Vector2(0, 10), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        FindObjectOfType<AudioManager>().Play("Jump");
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}

void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Enemy"))
    {
        TakeDamage(50);
    }
    if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = true;
    }
}
```

If I jump and land on ground, and after that if I dont use jump, e.g if I'm falling off the platform I can use that jump. Why does it get stacked? I want to use my jump only when Im touching the ground. I have attached the screen shot of the code for jumping as well.

Comment: where is your jump code ? onUpdate? this sound that your jump condition work faster that your land collision. Move your bool "isGrounded=false" to the first line before addForce.

Comment: No it is in Fixedupdate method.

Comment: I moved the is Grounded =false above addforce it didnt do anything..

Comment: The `if (Physics.OverlapSphere ...) return;` essentially does nothing, because it's the last statement in the method. It's not relevant to the problem. Please provide [mre]s on this site

Comment: I removed the if statement you mentioned. The problem is still there. Basically the problem is that when I'm jumping from ground to another ground the jump power is increased and player goes higher than he should. If you can kindly figure out something that i am doing wrong. It'll be great.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Sir I added picture of code for jump earlier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you enable your jumping with `isGrounded = true;`, you can use it once again. If you want to disable for example when you are falling off the platform, I would try:

```
void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision other)
{
    if (collision.collider.CompareTag("Ground"))
    {
        isGrounded = false;
    }
}
```

So that the jumping also gets disabled when you are not touching the ground, but not only for the case when you have jumped but for any other.

Comment: I have tried this but it didnt solve the problem sir

Comment: actually It worked with this method

Comment: glad that helped :)

Comment: Thankyou So much sir! Kindly give an effort like :)